# What is the exact difference between 'Hi' and 'Hello'?

Tags: american-english

What is the actual difference between 'Hi' and 'Hello'? When to use 'Hi' and when to use 'Hello'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hi" is a informal diminutive of "Hello". "Hi" and "Hello" are both greetings.

"Hello" generally should be used in more formal contexts, but it can be used in informal conversation as well, without seeming out of place.

Comment: Note: a comedian on TV recently said "I delete all emails starting with **Hi** without reading them".